# Redirecting log4j stdout to an InputStream

Tags: java, log4j, stdout, inputstream, system.out

The system I'm working on uses a library that prints its results using `log4j`. I'm not acquainted with `log4j`'s abilities, so I'm not sure how to capture the results. The library uses a configuration file that can be changed, so I can manipulate the output. What I want to do is capture the output in a stream without writing it on the FS. I tried redirecting the `System.out` but that ended up redirecting the `System.out` of the caller class, not the `log4j`.

Answer (score 2):

So, from your question, I take it you know that you can have appenders that write, for example, into a file or into stdout.

Now, it looks like you want to write to an OutputStream of your own, which means you'll anyway need to programatically access the object. I'd then say you need to write your own appender, which is actually pretty simple. Here's a [enter link description here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2004/jw-1220-toolbox.html) tutorial, though there's probably plenty (shorter) ones, depending on what you need